# How to save to browser Cache in unity WebGL?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a WebGL game for Unity and I can't find anything about how to save user data, the best I could find were people talking about saving to the browser to the cache, but no one talked about how to do that, just how to load from it, the act of saving seemed to be implied. How do you save to the browser cache in Unity when building for webGL?

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1095407/saving-webgl.html